# Ionic BarcodeScanner does not work on ios

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I created  an ionic app, it is work on android good. But the barcode scanner is not working correct in ios.

My code;

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function (barcodeData) {
  console.log("Data : "+barcodeData.text);
});
```

But XCODE giving me something like that as non-stop;
[image]

When I tried to this;

```
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  },
  {
      "preferFrontCamera" : true, // iOS and Android
      "showFlipCameraButton" : true, // iOS and Android
      "prompt" : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // supported on Android only
      "formats" : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
      "orientation" : "landscape" // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
  }
};
```

getting this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController: 0x15f30c400> on <MainViewController: 0x15dd4fab0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: not solved yet. please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing this i'm able to scan QR code in iOS.

- Add iOS Platform:

  ```
  ionic platform add ios
  ```
- Install ngCordova

  ```
  bower install ngCordova
  ```
- Added Barcodescanner plugin like this:

  ```
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
  ```
- index.html

  ```
  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scanBarcode()">
        <i class="icon ion-qr-scanner"></i>
        Scan Now
  </button>
  ```
- app.js

  ```
  angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','ngCordova']) // include ngCordova

  // Scan 
  angular.module("myApp").controller('scanner',function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {
  $scope.scanBarcode = function() {
  $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
      alert(imageData.text);
      console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
      console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
  }, function(error) {
      console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
  });
  };
  });
  ```

My nodejs version : v5.5.0

Phonegap version : 6.0.2

Ionic version : 1.7.14

Comment: actually barcode scanner is running and trying to scan. but its cannot getting result...

Comment: @AhmetDemir i'm getting result now in ionic too. have you check with proper bar code?

Comment: @AhmetDemir yes my config.xml file only contains this many setup for ios platform. can you attach or link the QR code that you are trying to scan?

Comment: @AhmetDemir i think it is qr code issue ... i'm also not able to scan that qr code.

Comment: Qr Code Created by Primefaces automatically. Can you send to me your qr code  that yu are trying too ?

Comment: what is difference between the two ? Any idea ?

Comment: @AhmetDemir Don't know :(

Comment: Thank you @Pushpa. You are saved my day... Thank you so much :)

Comment: @AhmetDemir most welcome. if my answer helped you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

I face the same error and i find the solution for 2 days without success

install file open plugin: [enter link description here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener)

then use

```
 Encode(textToEncode){

this.barcodeScanner.encode(this.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE,
  textToEncode).then((data) =>{
    
    this.fileOpener.open(data.file, 'image/jpeg');
   
  },(err)=>{
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
  })
```

}

it's working fine

Result in the screenshot here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have scanner problem before, for no reason when i click button to fire scanner function it fired twice... so i have to work other way around.

HTML

```
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>
```

controllers

```
$scope.scannerOpened = false;

$scope.barcodeSearch = function() {
    if(!$scope.scannerOpened) {
        $scope.scannerOpened = true;
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(
                function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            ).finally(function() {
                $scope.scannerOpened = false;
            });
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply but,Unfortunately İt is not working

Comment: Can you show us your barcodescanner version? "Ionic plugin list"

Comment: phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 5.0.0 "BarcodeScanner" @Ben

Comment: and when i use $ionicPlatform.ready.. button never shown anything

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.Project" version="0.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Masada</name>
  <description>
       Masada Mobile
    </description>
  <author email="mail@gmail.com" href="http://example.com/">
      Company
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  
  
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources\ios\splash\Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources\ios\icon\icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="resources\wp8\splash\SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" height="1280"/>
    <icon src="resources\wp8\icon\ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99"/>
    <icon src="resources\wp8\icon\Background.png" width="159" height="159"/>
  </platform
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My QR Code was consisting of 16 characters. It was the cause of my problem, now it is solved. Thank you @Pushpa.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the ios library, it only contains the following types of formats, so it does not work for iOS. If you find some method to scan PDF417 in ios using ionic, you can share it!

```
typedef enum BarcodeFormat {
    BarcodeFormat_None = 0,
    BarcodeFormat_QR_CODE,
    BarcodeFormat_DATA_MATRIX,
    BarcodeFormat_UPC_E,
    BarcodeFormat_UPC_A,
    BarcodeFormat_EAN_8,
    BarcodeFormat_EAN_13,
    BarcodeFormat_CODE_128,
    BarcodeFormat_CODE_39,
    BarcodeFormat_ITF
} BarcodeFormat;
```

I invite you to review the response in [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner, type PDF417 bar-codes using ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549782/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner-type-pdf417-bar-codes-using-ionic/43433782#43433782)

Comment: As you see at the top my issue is already solved. My issue was't about PDF417, it's about number of barcode generetor character.

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Settings in iOS 10+

A significant change in iOS 10+ is that you must declare ahead of time any access to private data or your App will crash.

Once you link with iOS 10+ you must declare access to any user private data types. You do this by adding a usage key to your app’s Info.plist together with a purpose string. The list of frameworks that count as private data is a long one

Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Photos, Bluetooth Sharing, Microphone, Camera, Location, Health, HomeKit, Media Library, Motion, CallKit, Speech Recognition, SiriKit, TV Provider.

You need to put the "NSCameraUsageDescription" in your plist.

Like

Key:- Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Type:- String

Value:- $(PRODUCT_NAME) uses Cameras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWRed.png)